# How to merge different finished features into master?

Tags: git, git-flow

How can I handle the following scenario using Git (Git Flow)?

I have two aligned branches: `master` and `develop` (respectively production and test enviroment).

I have to implement two new features so I have two new branches from develop: `feature/feature-a` and `feature/feature-b`.

These two features are completed so I merge them into `develop`.

Now I can merge them in my production enviroment with a `Pull request` from `develop` to `master` (is this correct?).

But how can I merge into `master`, for example, only `feature/feature-a`?

And what about a `release` or `hotfix` branches? These two could be used in my situation?

Comment: Since you mention `git-flow` as a tag, have you read and understood the guidelines that accompanies this workflow? They should answer those questions for you. Be aware that if you ask for "the *best* way", the question should be closed as "Primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Yes, I read and I understood. But don't know how to handle this. I read I can finish a feature using gitflow command. But how can I finish both and merge only one into master. Thanks for tip about "best way"

Comment: you can deploy them using your deployment method. If you are using a bulid system, you can usually specify which branch to be the target of that build system. In consiquence, you can merge you `dev` into `master`, then build from there, or complire, or just send out, etc. If you want to specifically deploy `feature-a`, well then again, it depends for what purpose you deploy it (only testing with a client?or maybe just for fun? or some PM wants that feature only).

Comment: I merged both features into `develop` in order to let client tests them. Now he wants only `feature-a` in production (`master`).

Comment: you can cherry pick 'merge feature-a into develop' comment into master

Answer (score 1):

You have an option of `git cherry-pick`. With cherry-pick, you can specify which commit you want to merge further to master. Cherry-pick specific commits from development and commit to master. [More about cherry picking](http://previousnext.com.au/blog/intro-cherry-picking-git)

Regarding release and hotfix, it is mostly opinion based. You can create a release branch from your master for every release (like `release/5.21`) and hotfix from release (like `hotfix/5.21.1`) and merge back hotfix to master, but again it is just an opinion and someone else might have a better solution for your situation.